# How do I use .filter() to filter by an object within an object?

Tags: javascript

I have one large `invoices` object contain many individual `invoice` objects. I want to filter for only the `invoice` objects that contain a search criteria in any of the `invoice` properties.

I've tried to use a combination of .forEach and .filter, but I don't think I fully understand how to chain them together

```
const invoices = { 1: {OrderID: "123", InvoiceID: "ABD", InvoiceDate: "2015-03-08T00:00:00-05:00", InvoiceAmount: "54061"},
2: {OrderID: "321", InvoiceID: "ABC", InvoiceDate: "2015-03-08T00:00:00-05:00", InvoiceAmount: "124031"}}

psudeo-code:

for each invoice in invoices
for each property in invoice
check if property value equals search input
return array of invoices.keys
```

In my example, if my search input = "ABC" I would like to return an array [2]. If there were multiple `invoice`s where InvoiceID == "ABC", then I would expect and array with all of those keys.

Comment: Why would `"ABC"` return an `array [2]`? Unless perhaps that was a typo - there's only one invoice where `InvoiceID: "ABC"`. Use `Object.values(invoices)` to get an array of the invoices, and then add `.filter()` to the end to select only those where `invoice.InvoiceId === searchInput`. (Side note: if you're going to use an object keyed with indexes, why not just an array in the first place?)

Comment: `forEach` and `filter` don't work with pure objects. Show us what you tried.

Comment: What is pure objects ? @Kévin

Comment: @ShantiswarupTunga - In JS, all *elements*' prototype inherit the `Object` one at the end, so for instance, an array **is** an object, that's why I wrote *pure object*. It is a term that I may should not use. But that's an element builded with the `Object`'s constructor (so with `new Object`, `{ ... }`, etc).

Comment: @Kévin Okay, I got it, I was trying to compare it with pure function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you dont have an array. You have an object.

> As Kévin Bibollet mentioned [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will not work with objects, because its made for arrays.

The solution could be looping through your object, checking by [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and pushing them to an output-array like i did here:

```js
const invoices = { 
  1: {OrderID: "123", InvoiceID: "ABD", InvoiceDate: "2015-03-08T00:00:00-05:00", InvoiceAmount: "54061"},
  2: {OrderID: "321", InvoiceID: "ABC", InvoiceDate: "2015-03-08T00:00:00-05:00", InvoiceAmount: "124031"}
}

function search(str) {
  var output = [];
  
  // loop through invoices
  for(var invoice in invoices){
    // loop through actual invoice
    for(var key in invoices[invoice]){
      // check if actual value includes the searchstring 
      if(invoices[invoice][key].includes(str)){
        // push into output-array
        output.push(invoices[invoice]);
        // break the look to avoid pushing it again if there are more matches
        break; 
      }
    }
  }
  
  // return the output-array
  return output;
}

console.log(search('ABC'));
```

Comment: "I would expect and array with all of those keys" which are missing from your result. Otherwise a quick Object.values(obj).filter(... would do the job too.

Comment: thanks! I knew that .filter() and .forEach were for arrays... duh!

Comment: Just an additional point, it's always better to pass in all dependants as function argument. search = (str, invoices) => { ... }